# PHP XPATH parse HTML how to get inner text BEFORE another nested tag

Tags: php, html, string, parsing, xpath

i'm ussing xpath to parse html with no problems until I found the code below.

I usually use the "textContent" property one I got this `td` with ax xpath query, BUT I need to get only the text BEFORE the `<img` tag.

```
   <td class="rowdispari">
                                ZONA NON SERVITA QUOTIDIANAMENTE-PROSSIMA CONSEGNA

                                                &nbsp;
                        <img onmouseover="caricaTool()" src="template/img/infoTip.png" width="17">
                            <div class="bottom" id='tooool'>
                                <div class="contenuto">
                                    <div class="top">
                                        <font class="testobold"><font class='testoblubold'>ZONA NON SERVITA QUOTIDIANAMENTE - PROSSIMA CONSEGNA </font><br>La località di destinazione non è tra quelle servite quotidianamente da SDA. La consegna avverrà al più presto possibile, compatibilmente con le operazioni logistiche.</font>
                                        <p>&nbsp;<br><a href="javascript:chiudiTool()"><u>Chiudi</u></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use:

```
//td[@class="rowdispari"][img[@src="template/img/infoTip.png"]]/text()[1]
```

or:

```
//td[@class="rowdispari"]/text()[following-sibling::img[@src="template/img/infoTip.png"]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have XPath to get the outer `<td>` element, you can simply append the XPath with `/text()[1]` to get the first text node that is direct child of current `<td>` element :

```
path_to_td_here/text()[1]
```

more concrete example :

```
//td[@class='rowdispari']/text()[1]
```